# B&R Automation Studio: I met the installation error 4735 during installation

Tags: error-handling, br-automation-studio

I have installed B&R Automation Studio:AS_4.12.2.93 but met the error code 4735 pop-up window like followed;

installation 4735 error

[image: 1]

> Automation Studio 4.12 Setup
>
> The installation of 'Prepare environment for AS' has been aborted with error code 4735

What is the problem in my notebook pc?
I am using Windows 10 English version.

I installed it in Windows 11 Korean. But the same error.

I want to know knowto fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install .NET Framework 3.5. The easiest way is to use Windows Features (can also be started with `Win+R` and then enter `control appwiz.cpl,,2`) and then tick `.NET Framework 3.5`.

(Just had the same issue and B&R support helped me :))